# Is it correct to say bancarella mobile di cibo?

Tags: idioms, phrase-request

I wish to describe a mobile stand that sells food in the street. I have constructed *bancarelle mobile di cibo* but I feel uncertain about my choice. Have I done it correctly or is there an Italian idiomatic phrase for caravans with a flap on the side for selling street-food? I am particularly interested in a Tuscan/Florentine term.

Comment: _Bancarelle mobili_ could be ok; I wouldn't use _cibo_, use _di beni alimentari_ instead. Could it be a van? Depending on the context _camioncini_ or _furgoncini_ or _carri_ could also be appropriate. If possible, clarify what kind of fruit is being sold.

Comment: That is why I want a Tuscano idiom. The stall I am writing about is for a lampredottai, not a fruttivendolo.

Comment: "ambulante" or "venditore ambulante" comes to mind.

Comment: What if you just say *la bancarella di un lampredottaio*? *Bancarella* somewhat implies in itself it is not a fixed structure. (Buono il lampredotto!)

Comment: *Banchetto* (just like the word for “banquet, feast”) is also heard for “stall”, but perhaps it is mostly used in Rome.

Comment: We use "bancarella"
or "si va da i sudicio" -> "let's go to *the man who sell food in streets*"

Comment: Can you elaborate on that and explain better? The phrase «si va da i sudicio» means «si va dal sudicio», i.e. «we go to the filthy one». Why would you say such a thing?

Comment: I agree that the answer should be made clearer, but in the meantime let me add that in Rome, quite analogously, it is not unusual to call a not too refined place to eat *sozzone* (where *sozzo*, i.e. “filthy” is close to *sudicio*, etymologically too), in an almost affectionate way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A generic definition that I think can be understood in all Italy can be **chiosco ambulante** or **chiosco mobile**.

I think that this is the best word choice to describe waht you are talking about, and I also found that this is the description used in some websites that talk about this job:

> Un buon sbocco di lavoro, senza investire eccessivo denaro, è diventare imprenditore di un **chiosco ambulante**; ...

http://lavoroefinanza.soldionline.it/aprire-un-chiosco-ambulante-168453.html

> **Come Aprire un Chiosco Ambulante**
>
> Aprire un **chiosco ambulante** può essere un processo complicato, richiede una cospicua quantità di denaro per avviarlo e molta pazienza.

http://it.wikihow.com/Aprire-un-Chiosco-Ambulante

If you want to underline the fact that the mobile stall is actually a caravan with a mobile stall, you should choose **furgone ambulante**, but **chiosco** better indicates the fact that food is sold from the mobile stall.

Hope this help!

Comment: A search for [lampredotto](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lampredotto) on Italian Wikipedia gives precisely this word: "chiosco".

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to describe a mobile stand that sells food in the street. I
>   have constructed bancarelle mobile di cibo but I feel uncertain about
>   my choice. Have I done it correctly or is there an Italian idiomatic
>   phrase for **caravans** with a flap on the side for selling street-food? I
>   am particularly interested in a **Tuscan/Florentine term.**

Il termine toscano/fiorentino è 'banchino', è tipico il 'banchino di trippaio' , questo sarebbe 'banchino di lampredottaio'.

Non credo che si possa usare per un mezzo motorizzato, altrove si direbbe 'chiosco (vendita alimenti) ambulante', 'autonegozio', 'lampredotteria ambulante' etc, ma gli italiani amano l'inglese persino chi vuole combattere il 'fast food' si definisce 'slow food, quindi 'caravan', 'camper'

> ...dalla porchetta di Ariccia alla trippa e al *lampredotto* fiorentini,
>   dalle bombette di Alberobello allo *street food* siciliano .. dagli
>   arrosticini abruzzesi al Pastin che arriva dalle dolomiti bellunesi.
>   Non mancherà il cibo di strada locale con scagliozzi e torcinelli,
>   ospitati dal **caravan** vintage..

etc:http://www.turismoallariaaperta.com/2012/09/26/7%C2%B0-festival-internazionale-del-cibo-di-strada/, 
http://italian.alibaba.com/product-gs/stainless-steel-mobile-food-catering-cart-hot-dog-caravan-596394928.html

Comment: A prescindere dalle generalizzazioni ascientifiche, il link che citi non fa testo perché è cinese, e tradotto automaticamente: «Orificio: shanghai ... Abilità del rifornimento: 500 Insieme/insiemi per Mese».

Comment: Io non conosco il gergo dei bancarellai motorizzati, ma quel sito, fino a prova contraria, è rappresentativo di come i traduttori automatici traducono i siti cinesi.  :-)

Comment: bobie, continuo a non capire: nel nuovo articolo di cui dai l'indirizzo non si usa né la parola *caravan* né *camper*, mentre si parla per esempio di cibo «servito nei caratteristici chioschi o offerto da venditori ambulanti». E quindi...? Invece se cerchiamo su Google ["furgone ambulante"](https://www.google.it/webhp?tab=ww&q=furgone+ambulante&safe=off#newwindow=1&q=furgone+ambulante&safe=off), come suggerito in un'altra risposta, troviamo centinaia di migliaia di risultati. Quindi, per ora, -1 per le affermazioni non sostenute da fonti, ma +1 per il “banchino”!